# Is there a way to tell if a Cards Against Humanity card exists already?

Tags: cards-against-humanity

I have Cards Against Humanity with all the expansion packs that come with blank cards. I have some ideas for cards but there are so many I couldn't possibly remember/know all the ones that already exist. Is there a way to search if a card exists without having to manually look through every single card?

I tried the PDF on the website but it does not seem to have the expansion packs and it is not searchable.

Comment: What prevents you from using CTRL-F to search through the PDF?

Comment: @atk I guess the cards are rendered as images and not text. Trying to search for a card I can see in the PDF says no results found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use these URLs to see the *current version* of the cards directly from CAH:

- http://cardsagainsthumanity.com/wcards.txt (White Cards)
- http://cardsagainsthumanity.com/bcards.txt (Black Cards)

These text files are updated frequently, whenever the base CAH set is updated.

For some expansions, .txt files also exist:

- http://www.cardsagainsthumanity.com/bcards1.txt (Expansion 1, Black Cards)
- http://www.cardsagainsthumanity.com/bcards2.txt (Expansion 2, Black Cards)

I wasn't able to turn up the white cards or other expansions through URL hacking.

There are also a couple of 3rd party sites and Github repos which have collected lists of the cards, both the main set and various expansions:

- http://mdsc.info/dropbox/cah/
- https://github.com/nodanaonlyzuul/against-humanity/blob/master/source/cards.json
- https://github.com/samurailink3/hangouts-against-humanity/wiki/Cards

Answer (score 1):

BoardGameGeek.com seems to have a [listing](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/85972/cah-cardlisting) through expansion 3.  You might be able to find more be going through the first couple pages of Google [search](http://bit.ly/1fYHnpc) results and second level links. This was found through the 3rd link in the search results.

Comment: I found mention of that, but was nope not to have to register on a site just to get a list of cards.